# Override Magento 2 CatalogImportExport import functionality

Tags: magento2

Could someone please suggest me on how to override the Magento2 defaults CatalogImportExport functionality.

Im stuck here as my Model class is not getting overridden.

I tried below links:

http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-programming-implement-import-with-import-xml

But upto no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can have look at our implementation on Improved Import https://github.com/firebearstudio/importexportfree

Comment: Hi @firebear team I would like to override the protected $_linkNameToId  variable from the Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product.php how to do? can you please advise